# Why is my MS Access form field auto-generating a blank line?

Tags: forms, null, line, field, auto-generate

Auto-generated blank line appears at top of MS Access form field upon creation. Datatype long text (text field on form). Did not appear on same forms with similar fields. Obviously a vbCrLf (carriage return, line feed) insert. Happens on multiple (similar) forms, same d/b app, but not with similar fields created earlier in time.

Not created by my code, or any field property that I can find.

I can manually delete the blank line.

Form field shows input but not recording in underlying query or table!

What's going on? What am I doing wrong? Where does it come from? Thoughts, please...

Ok, needs further research. Don't waste time on this one. Maybe I can figure this one out.

Many thanks,
Cliffhanger